# Existence of minimum - Mathematical argument

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Given the function $$ f(x,y) = (x+ \frac{1}{2})^2+(y+\frac{1}{2})^2$$
where  $x^2+y^2\geq 1$
, how can I argue that a minimum for this function exist? I know that I can find it using Lagrange but I have to argue why there is a minimum. Geometrically I can see it as minimizing the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2})$, which is a point in the interior of the unit circle, where  (x,y) are not in the unit-circle. Obviously it exist but I need a mathematical argument

Comment: The condition on (x, y) is that $x^2+ y^2\ge 1$.  The "$\ge$" is important.  Do you see that it would **not** be true if it were $x^+ y^2>   1$"?

Comment: I think you want to start from the fact that continuous functions on compact subsets will attain their extremum values. Your function $f(x,y)$ is polynomial, hence continuous. The domain $x^2 + y^2 \ge 1$ is closed, but not compact. But if you observe that as $(x,y)$ moves away from $0$, $f(x,y)$ decreases, so when searching for the minimum you can restrict yourself to looking at a doughnut shape region given by $\{ x^2 + y^2 \le 2 \} \setminus \{ x^2 + y^2 \ge 1 \}$. This region is compact, and then you can apply the fact.

Comment: I have thought about the fact that you write “as (x,y) moces away from 0, f(x,y) decreases”. Is it true? Is it somehow similar to say as (x,y) moves from (-0.5,-0,5) in all directions, f(x,y) increases? And then take a feasible point like (1,1) with $x^2+y^2= 2$ and then get the compact set from that? Saying that we can find (x,y) in this set that is “closer” or at least as close to (-0.5,-0.5) than (1,1) and thereby have a lower f

Comment: It's very simple for the case you presented. Your objective function is coercive, and coercive functions attains the minimum value over a closed set

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is not difficult to determine the point which attains the minimum of $\ f\ $—namely, $\ \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\ $.

Let $\ p_0=\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ $, then $\ f(p)=\left\|p-p_0\right\|^2\ $ for all $\ p\in \mathbb{R}^2\ $, and if $\ \|p\|^2\ge1\ $, then $\ \|p\|\ge1\ $, and
\begin{align}
\left\|p-p_0\right\|&\ge\|
p\|-\left\|p_0\right\|\\
&\ge1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ .
\end{align}
Therefore $\ f(x,y)=\left\|(x,y)-p_0\right\|^2\ge\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\ $ for all $\ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\ $ with $\ x^2+y^2\ge1\ $. But if $\ p^*=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\ $, then $\ \left\|p^*\right\|^2\ge1\ $ and
$$
\left\|p^*-p_0\right\|=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ ,
$$
so $\ f(p^*)=\left\| p^*-p_0\right\|^2= \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\ $. By definition, therefore, $\ p^*\ $ is a minimum of $\ f\ $ over the set $\ \left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\,\left|\,x^2+y^2\ge1\right.\right\}\ $.